# Android TabLayout vs SlidingTabLayout

Tags: android

When should I used the standard TabLayout vs the SlidingTabLayout that shows up in this Project: http://developer.android.com/samples/SlidingTabsBasic/index.html. Whats gives, and why the two different tab classes?

Comment: That sample was made in 2013, before api-23 (Android 6) support design library was released, you can see the copyright date here: http://developer.android.com/samples/SlidingTabsBasic/src/com.example.android.common/view/SlidingTabLayout.html   Now that the support design library gives you a standard implementation for tabs with TabLayout, it's the easiest and also "latest and greatest" way to do tabs.  This is probably the best guide for TabLayout: https://guides.codepath.com/android/google-play-style-tabs-using-tablayout

Comment: @DanielNugent thank you